# Mounting AWS S3 bucket using AWS IAM roles instead of using a passwd file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I am mounting an AWS S3 bucket as a filesystem using [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). It requires a file which contains AWS Access Key Id and AWS Secret Access Key. 
How do I avoid the access using this file? And instead use AWS IAM roles?

Answer (score 2):

As per [Fuse Over Amazon](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon) document, you can specify the credentials using 4 methods. If you don't want to use a file, then you can set AWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY environment variables.
Also, if your goal is to use AWS IAM instance profile, then you need to run your s3fs-fuse from an EC2 instance. In that case, you don't have to set these credential files/environment variables. This is because while creating the instance, if you attach the instance role and policy, the EC2 instance will get the credentials at boot time. Please see the section 'Using Instance Profiles' in page 190 of [AWS IAM User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/iam-ug.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

there is an argument `-o iam_role=---` which helps you to avoid AccessKey and SecretAccessKey

The Full steps to configure this is given below 
https://www.nxtcloud.io/mount-s3-bucket-on-ec2-using-s3fs-and-iam-role/